# Recording stereo mix from YouTube to Renoise

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, youtube, jack

I am using Ubuntu Studio with Renoise working with sample based music.

I can watch videos on YouTube in Chrome/Firefox and record the Stereo Mix straight into Audacity using "ALSA" as host and "pulse" as recording and playback. I can also connect Audacity/VLC, etc. to Renoise using Jack (QJackCtl) to record the Stereo Mix from playback there into Renoise.

However, whenever I have Renoise running regardless of the host used for playback/recording, YouTube videos just freeze until I exit Renoise.

Is there anyway to record from YouTube straight into Renoise?

I'm using built the built in laptop soundcard with no second external audio interface or card.

Many thanks.
J

Comment: have you tried using 'youtube-dl' ? it can download and extract audio to a local file that could then be imported to renoise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more searching online I found the steps in this YouTube video got it working for me:
[Jack and PulseAudio Together as Friends - Linux](https://youtu.be/6J-RQudJx30)

Basically edit /etc/pulse/default.pa to add the following under `### Load audio drivers statically`

```
load-module module-jack-sink
load-module module-jack-source
```

then kill pulseaudio. After that I could connect PulseAudio Jack Sink in QJackCtl.